# Meta data driven work flow in activiti

Tags: activiti, business-process-management

Is it possible to create a work flow dynamically based on the table. Suppose I have a table (File) where there are some user tasks and those tasks should be assigned to groups based on the column value. How to configure a workflow dynamically in activiti

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the dynamic workflow, but regarding your problem. Below is my understanding :

- you want to assign a task to a particular groups on the basis of value in table. e.g.
  user1    -   Reviewer1
  user2    -   Reviewer2
  correct if am wrong.

  For this one resolution can be, you can use expression in 'Candidate Groups' property like '${Reviewer}'.

Create a service Task before this above user task, which evaluates 'Reviewer' value in advance. i.e. this task will fetch the reviewer's valuse form table, and assign same to Reviewer process variable.